# Disableing Chrome Autofill (again) 70.0.3538.67

Tags: angular, google-chrome, input, autocomplete, angular-material2

with chrome version 70.0.3538.67 all previous hacks disabling autofill/autosuggest no longer work.

I'd like something clean within reason.

Also I have some forms with a mix of fields which shouldn't suggest and fields that should. (<- if this is impossible without either separating into two forms or resorting to dirty hacks then I'll probably separate the forms)

btw I use angular and material 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that using `autocomplete="off"` works as expected now for Google Chrome v70 instead of using `autocomplete="randomstring"`. However I cannot see any reference to Google making this amend in the changelogs, so this may change again. But at the time of writing this, the above method works.